# What do static and final mean for a package?

Tags: java, static, package, final

I accidentally discovered that prefixing a package declaration by `static` or `final` does not give any error. I Googled about static/final packages but couldn't find any results. What do these prefixes mean for packages? Was this an error in my IDE? I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04

Example 1:

```
static package one;

public class FooBar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Example 2:

```
final package one;

public class FooBar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Output of both of these is `Hello World`

Comment: Could you show what you mean? I do get errors when doing that.

Comment: This does not work. In the future its a good idea to include the minimum code which can recreate your problem.

Comment: The eclipse compiler has some minor differences with the official Oracle java compiler. You appear to have hit one such, where ecj compiles code that is technically invalid.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? In my Eclipse Neon 4.6, this does not compile.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You're probably right. But my doubt is that if the compiler has compiled this code into byte code, why don't I get a run-time error when the Java run-time tries to execute this?

Comment: Obviously there is no corresponding byte-code for invalid instructions. If it is compiling, those keywords are being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

That code is not compiling nor running since java doesnt allow modifiers in the package declaration...

and as you can see in the oracle [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) they are  specificated for Classes or members, not for packages...